# Action editor's active action

Tags: nla-editor

I'm designing a stack of animations for a game, and once in a while the display will get stuck on an animation, regardless of the action I edit. How do I change the active action displayed in the rectangle I show in the arrow?

[image: active action]

Comment: The action called Assassin_Idle.006 is probably opened in the Dope Sheet, so simply close it?

Comment: Nope, as I explained what I pointed at doesn't change if I switch the action. Could it be a bug because I change the action while playing it?

Comment: is it working the same in 2.79?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it's because appended/new actions are added under the current selected item, which can be a mesh or an armature.