# Model and Armature need to have actions changed separately?

Tags: animation, armature

I have a model I created which includes a few different animations - in this case it is a gun, includes "shoot" and "reload". Those are two actions. But it seems each action exists independently on the armature and the mesh. On the action editor, if accidentally the animation is changed for the mesh, nothing happens:
[image]
if however it is changed for the armature it seems to have the intended effect.

Therefore,

1. What is the difference between setting the action on the mesh and on the armature?
2. Is it possible to have the actions on the armature only to avoid confusion?
3. If not is it possible to have them both switch at the same time?

I've found those two related questions:

1. [This guy on this Blender StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216029/action-editors-active-action): apparently was trying to set actions on the mesh, which wouldn't work and the animation would seem stuck. He said "it's because appended/new actions are added under the current selected item, which can be a mesh or an armature" but he doesn't elaborate whether he managed to add them to the armature only
2. [This guy on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/ajdukp/model_and_armature_need_to_have_actions_changed/): has the same issue I have essentially, to quote "Is there a way to keep them together so switching actions doesn't require doing it twice?"

The file I am noticing this issue on is [this one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bZMncfKR04BbYRVoJnax5LW6qVjgDz17/view?usp=sharing) for completeness  but it is very far from special.

P.S. I use Blender v2.79 but AFAIK (having tested it quickly) the issue is exactly the same on 2.8x/2.9x.

Comment: if your gun is supposed to be animated by the armature, only give the action to the armature. Also you don't tell anything about what this gun is supposed to do so it's hard to guess the best way to do something, but I doubt there's any good reason to assign action to the gun object itself

Comment: Anything you're doing on the mesh can be done on the armature.  Even shapekeys etc can be driven from the positions (or whatever) of bones in the armature.  Your best bet is to not have an action on the gun at all, because then you don't have to worry about ever syncing anything on the NLA.

Comment: @moonboots it is supposed to be exported for use in videogames. I haven't deliberately assigned actions to the mesh, I probably did it through ignorance, how do I avoid that in the future? or how can I make the action unassignable to the mesh?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've accidentally assigned the same action to both the object and the armature when you actually need to assign it to the armature only, as it is controlling the object.

To remove the action, select the object (gun), open the *Dope Sheet*, switch it to *Action* mode, click on the X button, it won't delete the action, it will just remove it from the selected object:

[image]

You can also go in the *Outliner* and under the gun object, right click on the action and *Clear Animation Data*:

[image]